# How to programmatically go back to root view controller with a global function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have 3 main VC (MyAccount, Register, Login). Then I have a Swift file(Manager.swift) where I set up a class function where after the registering or logging in it would dismiss the VC.

Manager.swift

```
class Manager {

  class func registerUser(vc: UIViewController?, user_email : String, user_password : String){
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: hostURL + "userRegister.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "user_email=\(user_email)&user_password=\(user_password)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Let’s convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

        let myJSON = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {

            let status = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            let msg = parseJSON["message"] as? String
            print("Status: \(status)")

            if(status != "Success")
            {
            UIAlert.displayAlert(vc, title: "Error", message: msg!, dismissTxt: "OK")
            }
            else{
                defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")

//My Failed attempt to go back to Root :C                    
vc?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}


}
```

RegisterVC

```
buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

  Manger.registerUser(self, user_email:username, user_password:password1234)

}
```

I used navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated in an attempt to back
It would work but sometimes the app would crash, spitting out this:

> 2015-10-02 14:51:01.410 Retail_Template[4551:261846] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:378
>   2015-10-02 14:51:01.415 Retail_Template[4551:261846] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x009f8a94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02b26e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x009f892a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
>       3   Foundation                          0x010bd3e6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
>       4   UIKit                               0x021f9d2e -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 180
>       5   UIKit                               0x019e14f2 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 703
>       6   UIKit                               0x019e122e -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:] + 60
>       7   UIKit                               0x01ddd1d6 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1208
>       8   UIKit                               0x01de6bef -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 502
>       9   UIKit                               0x01de6c85 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:] + 57
>       10  UIKit                               0x0190dd0a -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 1029
>       11  UIKit                               0x01903bf4 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 5104
>       12  UIKit                               0x01913c0b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 801
>       13  UIKit                               0x01914d05 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68
>       14  UIKit                               0x01aded9f -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252
>       15  UIKit                               0x017cb16b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 813
>       16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02b3b059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x003ed60c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x003e128e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
>       19  QuartzCore                          0x003e10f2 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
>       20  QuartzCore                          0x003d3c2b _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
>       21  QuartzCore                          0x00407c23 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 589
>       22  QuartzCore                          0x00407fbd _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 289
>       23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04bc32f7 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 93
>       24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04bc3051 _pthread_exit + 108
>       25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04bc3734 pthread_get_stackaddr_np + 0
>       26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x04bc0e0e start_wqthread + 30
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error says:

> may only be called from the main thread.

Your operation should be called into main thread. As shown into below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //Perform your task here.
}
```

Comment: I see. so that's is what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, Just add this in your code and it will work fine..:)